# Entity-Framework Derived dbContext Configuration exception

Tags: entity-framework, exception, dbcontext, derived

I made a DLL to include in an ASP (MVC) project, in the DLL there is some 'base' functionality and ofcourse, I'm including it in other MVC projects.
The problem is I have a EF - Code first project now and it's using a Configuration class for the migrations:

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Project.Models.DbContextTest>
    {
        public Configuration()
        {
            //AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        }

        protected override void Seed(Project.Models.DbContextTest context)
        {
            //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.

            //  You can use the DbSet<T>.AddOrUpdate() helper extension method 
            //  to avoid creating duplicate seed data. E.g.
            //
            //    context.People.AddOrUpdate(
            //      p => p.FullName,
            //      new Person { FullName = "Andrew Peters" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Brice Lambson" },
            //      new Person { FullName = "Rowan Miller" }
            //    );
            //
        }

    }
```

When I'm using this configuration i get the following exception:

```
Sequence contains more than one matching element
```

On the following function:

```
return orderBy != null ? orderBy(query).ToList() : query.ToList();
```

The function is not the problem, because when i remove the configuration class everything is working fine. 
The exception is thrown on a query where I get a list of a table, it only has a Primary Key and no related tables (Foreign Keys).

The configuration class is empty, so I'm wondering what it's doing to make my Dll broken?

Thanks in advance,
Stefan

Comment: Interesting problem. Couple of guesses. 1) There's definitely only a single configuration class in the project? 2) As you're overriding the constructor, perhaps it's worth calling the base constructor too? Both questions are pure speculation I'm afraid!

Comment: 1) yes only one configuration class.
2) I tried but this didn't solve the problem.

Comment: When you debug and it calls the line that errors, is it calling the configuration method? Also, is there any more detail in the exception, perhaps an `InnerException`?

Answer (score 0):

It was a combination of starting the project and doing manual migration.
When starting the project it's auto migrating the code-first models, this in combination with the manual migration gives this errors / exceptions.